# how to arrange alphabetically (xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

i want to arrange the cell values alphabetically but i am not being able to arrange the values 
the code that i am working on

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


   cell.textLabel.text = [[[map annotations] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

return cell;
}
```

how can i arrange the cell.textLabel.text values alphabetically , any help will be appreciated

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That method is way too late;  by the time that method is called, the order should already be determined.

Why not simply sort the annotations into the order you want.   i.e. sort the array returned by `[map annotations]` prior to the table view's drawing of itself.

Answer (score 1):

As easy means of achieving this would be to sort the map annotations NSArray before you use it in the table cells, using of the many NSArray sorting options. (e.g.: `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`.)

See the [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for full details.

However, you'd want to do this *before* it's used inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (rather than inside it), to reduce needless overhead.

Comment: is this the way to do it ?
[[[map annotations] title] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Comment: Nope;   that won't work.  You need to sort the array as @middaparka describes.

Comment: @ middaparka could you please tell me or give me example , i didnt know how to do it before cellforrowatindexpath but i could do it inside cellforrowatindexpath ,it worked but it lead to a memory error